# Maintain css background image on SPAN when in Submenu

Tags: css, hover, submenu

Please see this PasteBin for my current code: http://pastebin.com/3RtjYN00

Currently when I hover over the main image, the image background position changes & a blue submenu appears - great!

However, when I hover over the blue submenu itself, the image returns to it's original non-hover background position.

How do I solve this problem so when I hover over the submenu the image stays in the "hover" state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to add any extra markup.

Simply change:

```
#mega li a#ship span:hover {
```

to

```
#mega li:hover a#ship span {
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/fmNCz/

Answer (score 0):

Add a div wrapper around your main image and your blue submenu. Than on the :hover of the wrapper, change the background-position of the children main image and set the blue submenu style to be visible.

This way, when you'll be hover the blue submenu, the image will stay in the "hover" state.

Edit:
Replace the 2 last lines of your css with those 2.

```
#mega li a#ship span{background:url('http://indiawebsearch.com/files/image/thumb_googlelogo.jpg') no-repeat; position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%;}
#mega li:hover a#ship span{background-position:0 -59px;}
```

I used your li as a wrapper and it's working fine on my side.

Comment: Is there any chance you could put together a quick code version using my Pastebin code? I'm a bit lost to be honest. Appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: It's done, I put the update in the my answer below Edit. Hope this help.

Comment: Many thanks for this, Simon. I'm going to try tw16's approach above, but this looks just as good.

Answer (score 0):

building on mcgarriers answer.

add this CSS

```
.mega-wrap:hover>#mega li a#ship span {
background: url('http://indiawebsearch.com/files/image/thumb_googlelogo.jpg') 0 -59px no-repeat;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

add this HTML

```
<body id="home">
<div id="container">    
   <div id="top">&nbsp;</div>    
   <div id="middle">   
   <div id="nav"> 
   <div class="mega-wrap">
   <ul id="mega">
   <li><a href="/shipping/" id="ship" class="shipping-info"><span>     </span>Home</a> 
   <b class="s4"></b> 
   <div> <b class="s1"></b><b class="s2"></b><b class="s3"></b><br /><br />
   <p><a href="#">Test Link 1</a></p> 
   </div>
   </li>
   </ul>  
   </div>
   </div>  
   </body>
```

however before you go any further I advice you to fix your html